# USB to USB data transfer using microcontroller

Tags: usb, communication, digital-communications

Is that possible that we can communicate two USBs,I mean data transfer between two USB without PC ?

How we can transfer data without PC between two USBs ?So please anybody can give me some idea how this stuff work ? Is there any special circuit or we can make it use of any controller ?
which type of micro controller is suitable? Do DMA(direct memory access) work in this scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by "USBs"? Are you talking about USB flash drives? USB requires a host and a slave, so you'll need a controller capable of transferring data between two USB mass storage devices.

Comment: I just want to know how we can transfer data between two USBs without using PC.

Comment: The edit only vaguely helps. What is missing is a clear and specific statement **from the op, not a 3rd party guess** of the devices referred to as "two USBs".  If it were "two USB flash drives" we might have something to work with.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. It is called **USB OTG** (On The Go). A protocol of USB where one (or both) devices can act as both a usb peripheral (i.e. a regular usb device) AND a usb host (i.e. acts like if it were a pc), depending on what cable you use. It's frequently used on cameras, printers, and some tablets or cell phones.

Answer (score 2):

These cables are/were commercially available and went under [various names and brands](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=usb+data+transfer+cable). The often proprietary drivers, hardware and supporting software has been largely replaced by standard Ethernet and supporting software which is standard available on most systems nowadays and only requires to be configured properly.

The simplest solution to implement this in USB is to connect two identical USB-to-(fast)-serial cables back to back, where TX and RX are crossed. Then run a protocol like [PPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_protocol) or [SLIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol) over it.

Comment: I think OP is talking about connecting two usb devices, like a flash drive and a camera, not two usb hosts (aka two pcs).